# my if is running twice, I wanted it to run only once using the -400

Tags: javascript

my if is running twice when I pass an account on it

so it is correct:

```
$("#listaPGG").scroll(function() { 
  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
    proximaPagina()
  }
});
```

so it performs twice:

```
 $("#listaPGG").scroll(function() { 
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight - 400) {
        proximaPagina()
      }
    });
```

how do i run it only once using the -400?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a variable that checks if the statement has been run:

```
var scrolled = false;
$("#listaPGG").scroll(function() { 
  if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight - 400 && !scrolled) {
    scrolled = true;
    proximaPagina()
  }
});
```